# simplilfy geojson file

Tags: geojson, simplify, topojson

I have a geojson file, but it's way too heavy for the app I need to develop

I'd like to know what alternative do I have to make it lighter.

I was thinking about simplifying it's shapes, and also turning to topojson.

Could you recommend me some tool to achieve this?

--

Edit: I saw the other thread stating how to convert to topojson, but I'd also like to simplify the shapes, they are much too detailed for the visualization I'm working on.

Comment: This is a very very late answer but for other people looking for a solution you can also use a node module called geojson-mend https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-mend.

Answer (score 3):

Use TOPOJSON, I had a 20 MB file and topojson simplified it down to 300 KB!

See here: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki for instructions and how to install.

You want to play with this parameter: --simplify-proportion